# Limit "prop_search" to Specific Types of Objects

Tags: python, scripting

Currently working on a piece of custom UI that contains an object selection box.

```
layout.prop_search(scene, "myselection", scene, "objects")
```

I'm wondering how I can make it so it only lists *objects* that contain a certain data type such as curves in the same way that the Follow Path constraint does.

[image: Follow path constraint prop_search]

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since blender 2.79 this is possible using the `poll` parameter of the [`bpy.props.PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointerproperty#bpy.props.PointerProperty).

```
import bpy    

class OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.prop(scene, "mychosenObject")

def scene_mychosenobject_poll(self, object):
    return object.type == 'CURVE'

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.mychosenObject = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=bpy.types.Object,
        poll=scene_mychosenobject_poll
    )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.mychosenObject


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**[See the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=pointerproperty#bpy.props.PointerProperty)**

> bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=None, name="", description="", options={'ANIMATABLE'}, poll=None, update=None)

Returns a new pointer property definition.
Parameters:

- **type** (`class`) – A subclass of bpy.types.PropertyGroup or bpy.types.ID.
- **name** (`string`) – Name used in the user interface.
- **description** (`string`) – Text used for the tooltip and api documentation.
- **options** (`set`) – Enumerator in [‘HIDDEN’, ‘SKIP_SAVE’, ‘ANIMATABLE’, ‘LIBRARY_EDITABLE’, ‘PROPORTIONAL’,’TEXTEDIT_UPDATE’].
- **poll** (`function`) – function to be called to determine whether an item is valid for this property. The function must take 2 values (self,object) and return Bool.
- **update** (`function`) – Function to be called when this value is modified, This function must take 2 values (self, context) and return None. Warning there are no safety checks to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the right collection, in this case `bpy.data.curves`:

```
import bpy    

class OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.prop_search(scene, "mychosenObject", bpy.data, "curves")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.mychosenObject = bpy.props.StringProperty()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.mychosenObject


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Explanation: [How to make my prop search show the objects in my scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43982/31447)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I want the list to only display _objects_ that have curve _data_, not the curve data itself.