# Rig Properties DISAPPEARED from the N panel

Tags: scripting, rigging, properties, rigify, panel

I imported a Rigged character named 'Abi' from the project files of a course I was following... (File > Append > Blend file > Collection...)

The rig was originally created with the Rigify add-on so, first time I had to run the script **(Abi_ui.py)** available with the rig to make some of its properties available in the **N Panel** ...

[image: running the scripy (Abi_ui.py)]

‎

[image: the options in the N Panel]

the second time I opened up Blender, those options from the **N Panel** were gone...
also, the **Script (Abi_ui.py)** was missing...

[image: N Panel options missing]

‎
[image: script missing]

I opened up the original file again *(the file provided in the course)*

Copied the script from there and ran it in My Version of that file...
now, I have to run that file every time I open blender...

**Is that any way I can save myself from that hassle...?**

and.........

**I'm not much experienced with blender, so Anyone... please Feel free to tell me that I'm doing it all wrong and if, there's a *Better* way of doing all that**

Comment: There are two options in the text editor panel "Text" menu, the first is "Make Internal" that stores your script in the .blend file, the second is the "register" checkbox which will make your script run when the file opens.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120700/how-to-make-a-text-file-dependent-of-an-armature-object-so-that-it-appends-with   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194681/rigify-automatically-link-ui-text-file-in-2-8  The red indicates it has no users, and hence is removed on close / re-open.

Comment: Thanks **Ron Jensen**