# How can I ensure that my 'rig_ui.py' file is loaded when the armature is linked and overridden in Blender 3.6?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, rigify

I managed to delete *rig_ui.py* the script of my rigify armature after renaming things somehow (at least *i think* that is the problem), and i don't know what to do to restore its original functionality, other than going back several files behind the actual one i got so i tried this fix:

Fetched the script from some versions behind (no code has been changed so it should be the same here) then manually pointed to the 'rig_ui.py' file in Blender by adding a Datablock pointer custom property to my rig just like:
[How to make a Text File dependent of an Armature object so that it appends with it to other projects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120700/how-to-make-a-text-file-dependent-of-an-armature-object-so-that-it-appends-with).
(in blender **3.6**)

However, when I link and then override my rig into a new project, the 'rig_ui.py' file doesn't seem to be automatically ran, **it's just there**. How can I ensure that my 'rig_ui.py' file is not only loaded but also executed along with my rig when I link it to another Blender project?

also i got the file and my preferences checked, those are not the problem afaik
[image] [image]