# Is there a way to make an object not-deleteable?

Tags: scripting, objects, outliner

I'd like to have an object that has some sort of special property so that it can't be deleted by accident.

for example:
if I press X, it will not delete this object but will instead deselect it or something

Can this be achieved with a custom property? or perhaps a script? outliner shenanigans?

Comment: A couple of available methods are giving an object a fake user, and / or making an object unselectable.  There is a difference between un-linking an object from the scene (or from its collection in the scene) and deleting it from the blend entirely.   An object with a fake user will not be removed from the blend with X, instead it  will be unlinked from the scene.  Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163695/object-referenced-by-pointerproperty-in-python-can-not-be-deleted-properly