# How to import text(scripted expression for driver) together when linking a character

Tags: python, linked-data

I used the phrase `bpy.app.driver_namespace` to create a function for scripted expansion that can be used in the driver and it works well in the local character file.

However, when I try to bring my character through a link in another blend file, the text is missing text. To use the character, you had to manually link text to set the execution and registration options.

However, the latest characters in Blender cloud, such as Spring and Rain, automatically come in with text when link.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194681/rigify-automatically-link-ui-text-file-in-2-8  (Same principle, assoc the text file to the model)

Comment: Thank you. The link was helpful.
When the following code is executed, text is associated with the object and the text moves together when you link the asset. `bpy.data.objects['my_armature']['my_script.py'] = bpy.data.texts['my_script.py']`