# What does `filter` parameter of Template_id do? and How to use it?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

In blender docs

```
template_ID(data, property, new='', open='', unlink='', filter='ALL', live_icon=False, text='', text_ctxt='', translate=True)
```

`filter (enum in ['ALL', 'AVAILABLE'], (optional)) – Optionally limit the items which can be selected`

From the available docs it looks like filter is used to filter out particular `id`s based on some sort of parameter.
I tried to add filter in blender ui's code where `template_id` is used. But didn't get any result.
So how can I use `filter` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linked to current scene, or any.**

[image]

Have used this for setting the active object, or pointer properties to `bpy.types.Object` instances.

- `'AVAILABLE'` for objects linked to context scene
- `'ALL'` for all objects in the blend file.

Setting an object not linked to a scene to the active object of that scene is going to cause issues.

GIF shows following  draw method used in  (*Used in gif above with `Templates > Python > UI Panel Simple`*)

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        col = layout.column()
        col.template_ID(context.view_layer.objects, "active", filter='AVAILABLE')
        col.template_ID(context.view_layer.objects, "active", filter='ALL')
```

See [Limit "prop_search" to Specific Types of Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75185/limit-prop-search-to-specific-types-of-objects)  re using poll to narrow down selection options for pointers.