# How to limit possible objects from an object chooser in Python

Tags: python, properties

I just read through this thread: [Object selection box in addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/object-selection-box-in-addon)

Is there a way to have similar function but to make the selection in the box limited to a list of objects defined by the programmer in Python? I realize that [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75185/limit-prop-search-to-specific-types-of-objects) answer defines the poll function that should be used, but what if it's dependent on more than just the object but a number of conditions that should be passed into the poll function (e.g., a sibling property in a PropertyGroup)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75185/limit-prop-search-to-specific-types-of-objects
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252679/how-to-add-a-filter-to-uilayout-prop

Comment: Hey! Really close, but the poll function that belongs to the PointerProperty is too limited for what I need to do.

Comment: Please create a new question that details what condition you're trying to check, add your attempt you've created so far and let us know what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Okay, I can do that. Thanks!

Comment: @AnsonSavage Just a note here, it looks like there may be a way to access the property itself using getters and setters: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#getter-setter-example