# Python - Pick collection with eyedropper

Tags: python, outliner

I have created a system that lets users assemble pieces from collections, placed inside of a master collection. Right now I am letting the users choose which one is the master by manually typing the name of it.

*But is there a way to get this information with the eyedropper tool instead?* And then access the name of what was chosen in that field?

For context, here I've actually named the collection "MasterCollection" but the system just looks for whatever name was typed in the UI. So if the user called it "BigCollection" they could then select it with the eyedropper directly. Or if they have multiple of these master collections, easily pick a different one:

[image]

And this is what the simple UI looks like right now, where I'd like to use the eyedropper instead of the StringProperty fields:

[image]

Comment: not a direct answer but you should use something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252682/86891

Comment: @Gorgious Oh nice, this almost solves the problem, thanks! It could still be problematic if the user has a lot of collections and overcrowds the list, but the searchability of the field does help with that so I'm definitely seeing this a viable alternative.

Comment: oh actually I thought this gave your an eyedropper on the field, it does with object pointers but not with collection pointer it seems